# SpecFlow :modify the report name generated using SpecFlow

Tags: specflow

Usually the SpecFlow report is generated using the projectName and name defined in your profile plus a time stamp: projectName_name_YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMSS
Is there any way I can modify this and give my custom report name?

Answer (score 0):

add `outputName="SpecRunReport.html"` into settings tag within the default.srprofile file in your project.

you can also use custom output templates by using the code below instead

```
<Settings projectName="DemoSpecflow" projectId="{Project ID}"/>
<Report>
    <Template name="CustomReportTemplate.cshtml"outputName="SpecRunReport.html"/>
</Report>
```